# Mule ESB - WMQ Connector - how to access WMQ message Header values

Tags: mule, ibm-mq

We are using Java 8, Mule ESB 3.7.2 with WMQ Connector.

This is Pub/Sub application and I have created subscribers with Unique Application Identity Data. This is available within IBM WMQ as MQMD.ApplIdentityData.

But, Mule message doesn't bring this header information. Is there any way to access this value in Mule flow?

Application Design is like this...

- 2 Flows. Flow #1 works as a Publish flow will publish into a WMQ Topic.
- WMQ Subscribers will be added into a WMQ - Queue.
- Flow #2 will be pickup each subscriber message and process.
- Each subscriber got unique Application Identity Data and I need to access that value in Flow #2 (Consumer Flow).

Mule - WMQ Connector:

```
<wmq:xa-connector name="WMQ" hostName="localhost" port="1414" queueManager="MyTestQM" transportType="CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ"   numberOfConsumers="10" cacheJmsSessions="true"/>

<wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="PUBLISH_QUEUE" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="WMQ"/>
```

Mule Message:

```
INFO  2016-03-16 16:44:10,941 [[pubsub].pubsubFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Consumer - 

org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=4f16e372-eb96-11e5-8945-ecb020524153
  payload=[B
  correlationId=ID:414d51204d7954657374514d202020206a5be95620018c3f
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

  Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
  INBOUND scoped properties:
        JMSCorrelationID=ID:414d51204d7954657374514d202020206a5be95620018c3f
        JMSDeliveryMode=1
        JMSDestination=topic://EIS_Test_Topic
        JMSExpiration=0
        JMSMessageID=ID:414d51204d7954657374514d202020206a5be9562001ea03
        JMSPriority=0
        JMSRedelivered=false
        JMSTimestamp=1458146650880
        JMSXAppID=MyTestQM                                                            
        JMSXDeliveryCount=1
        JMSXUserID=Santhosh-Kum
        JMS_IBM_Character_Set=ISO-8859-1
        JMS_IBM_Encoding=273
        JMS_IBM_Format=                        
        JMS_IBM_MsgType=8
        JMS_IBM_PutApplType=26
        JMS_IBM_PutDate=20160316
        JMS_IBM_PutTime=16441088
        MULE_CORRELATION_ID=ID:414d51204d7954657374514d202020206a5be95620018c3f
        MULE_MESSAGE_ID=ID:414d51204d7954657374514d202020206a5be9562001ea03
        MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.wmq.PUBLISH.QUEUE
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
  SESSION scoped properties:
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule ESB will truncate header values from MQ Message once received before post it to the flow.

Mulesoft is enhancing connector(s).

Until then, only available option is Java Listener with Polling. I will post, if I hear anything otherwise.

Comment: Mule responded with a batch for WMQ Connector/Transported to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access any `MQMD` field by pretending it is a property. So you could ask for the property `Root.MQMD.ApplIdentityData`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How could I access this property in Mule? would that be in Inbound? 

I have tried `System.out.println("Root.MQMD.ApplIdentityData ::::: " + muleMsg.getProperty("Root.MQMD.ApplIdentityData"));`. 

But, I have received null.

Comment: I don't know mule, but your question looks like you are using JMS, so can't you just use Root.MQMD.AppIdentityData as a JMS property name and retrieve it like any other JMS property?

Comment: It works in standalone Java client, but not within mule. I just received word from Mule guys and they are fixing the issue. And, Thanks for information, another way of taking Header values. I was retrieving using JMS_IBM_MQMD_xyz....